# Sita nam mahima in Lomash samhita

Tags: sita

What was the ma Sita nam mahima in Lomash Samhita?
What say Lomash Samhita about ma Sita name?

### mata Sita nam mahima##

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are atleast 4 scriptures that I now know , which says about importance of sita
These are:-

1. Bhavisya puran
2. Lomesh samhita
3. Brahma Ramayana
4. Aadi Ramayana

Sita naam mahima in lomesh samhita

**यज्ञ दान तपस्तीर्थ स्वाध्याय आत्मबोधतः।
कोटि संख्यं राम नाम्नि पावित्र्यं वर्तते प्रिये।।
ततः कोटि गुण पुण्यं सीता नाम सनातनम्।
इति ज्ञात्वा भजन्तयेतान् मुनयो नारदादयः।।**

Lomesh samhita

परमेश्वर सदाशिव कहते हैं – यज्ञ, दान, तप,तीर्थ, वेद अध्ययन, आत्म ज्ञान आदि कर्मों से जितना फल मिलता है उसका कोटि गुणा फल “राम” नाम से ही मिलता है और श्रीराम नाम का कोटि गुणा फल “सीता” नाम से ही प्राप्त होता है।

God Sadashiv says – whatever sacrifice, charity, austerities, pilgrimage, study of the Vedas, self-knowledge, etc., yields , that fruit of the millions of times is gained by chanting "Rama" once and ***the yield of chanting of name of Sri Rama millions of times is gained by the name of "Sita"  once.***

Almost same thing is written also in aadi ramayan but it is said by devrishi narada